# I get a "Build Failed" error when I try to use pyenv install "python version"

Tags: python, build, environment-variables, pyenv

I get the below issue when I run `pyenv install "python version"`. Not sure how to fix or what the problem is. I've looked through the majority of resources, but nothing I've seen specifies what the issue is. Does this have to do with Xcode?

I've installed pyenv and deadline using brew as well. Not sure if any additional information is required .

```
Installing Python-3.6.6...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/jm/4jb4_j8n56vbgn8g199dgj9r0000gn/T/python-build.20191108150321.45995
Results logged to /var/folders/jm/4jb4_j8n56vbgn8g199dgj9r0000gn/T/python-build.20191108150321.45995.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... darwin
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/jm/4jb4_j8n56vbgn8g199dgj9r0000gn/T/python-build.20191108150321.45995/Python-3.6.6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Below is my config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by python configure 3.6, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6 --libdir=/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Phillips-MacBook-Pro.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 19.0.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 16.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 566 tasks, 2364 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 4.78, Mach factor: 0.99
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.15/libexec
PATH: /Users/phillipbeltre/anaconda3/bin
PATH: /Users/phillipbeltre/anaconda3/condabin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /opt/X11/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2795: checking build system type
configure:2809: result: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
configure:2829: checking host system type
configure:2842: result: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
configure:2872: checking for python3.6
configure:2888: found /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
configure:2899: result: python3.6
configure:2999: checking for --enable-universalsdk
configure:3046: result: no
configure:3069: checking for --with-universal-archs
configure:3084: result: no
configure:3234: checking MACHDEP
configure:3443: result: darwin
configure:3464: checking for --without-gcc
configure:3487: result: no
configure:3490: checking for --with-icc
configure:3510: result: no
configure:3634: checking for gcc
configure:3661: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
configure:3890: checking for C compiler version
configure:3899: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang --version >&5
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/phillipbeltre/anaconda3/bin
configure:3910: $? = 0
configure:3899: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -v >&5
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/phillipbeltre/anaconda3/bin
configure:3910: $? = 0
configure:3899: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -V >&5
clang-4.0: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang-4.0: error: no input files
configure:3910: $? = 1
configure:3899: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -qversion >&5
clang-4.0: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang-4.0: error: no input files
configure:3910: $? = 1
configure:3930: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3952: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe  -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs conftest.c  >&5
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3956: $? = 1
configure:3994: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
| #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
| #define _BSD_TYPES 1
| #define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3999: error: in `/var/folders/jm/4jb4_j8n56vbgn8g199dgj9r0000gn/T/python-build.20191108150321.45995/Python-3.6.6':
configure:4001: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe '
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_MACHDEP_set=
ac_cv_env_MACHDEP_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=set
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig/:
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
ac_cv_prog_PYTHON_FOR_REGEN=python3.6
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ABIFLAGS=''
AR='/Users/phillipbeltre/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar'
ARCH_RUN_32BIT=''
ARFLAGS=''
BASECFLAGS=''
BASECPPFLAGS=''
BLDLIBRARY=''
BLDSHARED=''
BUILDEXEEXT=''
CC='x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang'
CCSHARED=''
CFLAGS='-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe '
CFLAGSFORSHARED=''
CFLAGS_ALIASING=''
CFLAGS_NODIST=''
CONFIGURE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=''
CONFIG_ARGS=' '\''--prefix=/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6'\'' '\''--libdir=/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib'\'' '\''CC=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang'\'' '\''CFLAGS=-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe '\'' '\''LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs'\'' '\''CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9'\'' '\''PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig/:'\'''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9'
CXX='x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++'
DEFS=''
DEF_MAKE_ALL_RULE=''
DEF_MAKE_RULE=''
DFLAGS=''
DLINCLDIR=''
DLLLIBRARY=''
DTRACE=''
DTRACE_HEADERS=''
DTRACE_OBJS=''
DYNLOADFILE=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENSUREPIP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='#'
EXT_SUFFIX=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLAPPSPREFIX=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKPYTHONW=''
FRAMEWORKUNIXTOOLSPREFIX='/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6'
GITBRANCH=''
GITTAG=''
GITVERSION=''
GNULD=''
GREP=''
HAS_GIT='no-repository'
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6_ARG=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTSONAME=''
LDCXXSHARED=''
LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs'
LDLAST=''
LDLIBRARY=''
LDLIBRARYDIR=''
LDSHARED=''
LDVERSION=''
LIBC=''
LIBFFI_INCLUDEDIR=''
LIBM=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPL=''
LIBRARY=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL_CRUFT=''
LINKCC=''
LINKFORSHARED=''
LIPO_32BIT_FLAGS=''
LLVM_PROFDATA=''
LLVM_PROF_ERR=''
LLVM_PROF_FILE=''
LLVM_PROF_FOUND=''
LLVM_PROF_MERGER=''
LN=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LTOFLAGS=''
MACHDEP='darwin'
MACHDEP_OBJS=''
MAINCC=''
MKDIR_P=''
MULTIARCH=''
MULTIARCH_CPPFLAGS=''
NO_AS_NEEDED=''
OBJEXT=''
OPT=''
OTHER_LIBTOOL_OPT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='https://bugs.python.org/'
PACKAGE_NAME='python'
PACKAGE_STRING='python 3.6'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='python'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.6'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PGO_PROF_GEN_FLAG=''
PGO_PROF_USE_FLAG=''
PKG_CONFIG=''
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig/:'
PLATFORM_TRIPLET=''
PY3LIBRARY=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORK=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR='no-framework'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKIDENTIFIER='org.python.python'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX=''
PYTHON_FOR_BUILD='./$(BUILDPYTHON) -E'
PYTHON_FOR_REGEN='python3.6'
PY_ENABLE_SHARED=''
RANLIB='/Users/phillipbeltre/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ranlib'
READELF=''
RUNSHARED=''
SED=''
SGI_ABI=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SHLIBS=''
SHLIB_SUFFIX=''
SOABI=''
SOVERSION='1.0'
SRCDIRS=''
TCLTK_INCLUDES=''
TCLTK_LIBS=''
THREADHEADERS=''
THREADOBJ=''
TRUE=''
UNIVERSALSDK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCH_FLAGS=''
USE_INLINE=''
USE_THREAD_MODULE=''
VERSION='3.6'
_PYTHON_HOST_PLATFORM=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_READELF=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin19.0.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin19.0.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users/phillipbeltre/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target=''
target_alias=''
target_cpu=''
target_os=''
target_vendor=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
#define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
#define _BSD_TYPES 1
#define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Looks like you only have a 32bit C compiler, but you need 64bit.

Comment: Where do you see that?

Comment: I checked to see if my computer was running 64-bit and it says Yes

Comment: `ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd`